# Android ListView OnItemClickListener event is not working

Tags: android, android-listview

My Activity class

```
private String[] mStrings2={"Title 01","Title 02"};
private String[] mStrings = {"Link to the image1", "Link to the image2"};

MyAdapter adapter;

        mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {              

            adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings, mStrings2);
            subList.setAdapter(adapternew);                       

        }
    });


MyAdapter class (MyAdapter.java)

    private Activity activity;
    private String[] data;
    private String[] data2;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

//Constructor
public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d, String[] mStrings2) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        data2=mStrings2;
        inflater = LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }
```

When I click on the First List Item, I want to load elements in second Array. But when executing the code I'm getting "NullPointerException". How to fix this. Pls guide me.

Edit....

```
    06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at com.java.hotelapp.Item_List$1.onItemClick(Item_List.java:106)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:282)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1037)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2449)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3073)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-12 14:21:42.499: E/AndroidRuntime(1429):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show the logcat where NPE happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see the declaration of `adapternew` adapter so it could be `null`..

```
subList.setAdapter(adapternew);
```

This line should be,

```
adapter = new LazyAdapter(MyActivity.this, mStrings, mStrings2);
subList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: yep, I corrected it, But still when I am click on a First list item getting NullPointerException

Comment: Thankx friend. Its working. But can you pls guide me what was the mistake?

Comment: I think in your LazyAdapter's constructor this refers to AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()'s object while MainActivity.this refers to activity context.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another suggestion:

```
mainList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
```

Could it be that `mainList == null` ?

And, please provide proper code and the exact moment and line of failure. The specific part of the stacktrace would also be nice.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView lv = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.listviewid);
lv.setItemsCanFocus(false); 

or try onlistitemclick

 @Override    
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {       
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
   super.onListItemClick(lv, v, position, id);  
 }
```